# Cant able to install newman error is reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain npm ERR

Tags: postman, newman

npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/newman failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\caf5103\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-10-31T06_46_46_854Z-debug-0.log

Tried to install with this comment - npm install -g newman . BUt getting error, how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN is an issue I had recently and the cause was changes made to our corporate proxy. I had to add the .pem file to Postman certificates, like this;

[image: Postman settings for CA Certificates]

Comment: Is there any other option to solve this, I was able to run the collection from the cmd but not able to take the report of the collection with the comment "-r htmlextra" at the end after the collection. Please suggest me to check whether the newman is installed properly.

Comment: @AbdulRahuman are you not seeing a report at all? are you specifying a save location? 
"...will create a new report in the ./newman directory, if the directory does not exist, it will be created as part of the Newman run."
You could specify a specific directory using "--reporter-htmlextra-export <path>"
https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman-reporter-htmlextra